# How I can make my jquery Flexslider move automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, opencart, flexslider

I am having trouble with the built-in slider in this theme: [Eda Opencart Theme](http://ps1.novademo.com/opencart/eda/)
I relised after purchase that it doesn't move automatically. Is there a way to change the javasript code to make it move eevry, let's say 4 seconds?

That's the code:

```
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.2.0
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Contributing Author: Tyler Smith
 */(function(e){e.flexslider=function(t,n){var r=e(t);r.vars=e.extend({},e.flexslider.defaults,n);var i=r.vars.namespace,s=window.navigator&&window.navigator.msPointerEnabled&&window.MSGesture,o=("ontouchstart"in window||s||window.DocumentTouch&&document instanceof DocumentTouch)&&r.vars.touch,u="click touchend MSPointerUp",a="",f,l=r.vars.direction==="vertical",c=r.vars.reverse,h=r.vars.itemWidth>0,p=r.vars.animation==="fade",d=r.vars.asNavFor!=="",v={},m=!0;e.data(t,"flexslider",r);v={init:function(){r.animating=!1;r.currentSlide=parseInt(r.vars.startAt?r.vars.startAt:0);isNaN(r.currentSlide)&&(r.currentSlide=0);r.animatingTo=r.currentSlide;r.atEnd=r.currentSlide===0||r.currentSlide===r.last;r.containerSelector=r.vars.selector.substr(0,r.vars.selector.search(" "));r.slides=e(r.vars.selector,r);r.container=e(r.containerSelector,r);r.count=r.slides.length;r.syncExists=e(r.vars.sync).length>0;r.vars.animation==="slide"&&(r.vars.animation="swing");r.prop=l?"top":"marginLeft";r.args={};r.manualPause=!1;r.stopped=!1;r.started=!1;r.startTimeout=null;r.transitions=!r.vars.video&&!p&&r.vars.useCSS&&function(){var e=document.createElement("div"),t=["perspectiveProperty","WebkitPerspective","MozPerspective","OPerspective","msPerspective"];for(var n in t)if(e.style[t[n]]!==undefined){r.pfx=t[n].replace("Perspective","").toLowerCase();r.prop="-"+r.pfx+"-transform";return!0}return!1}();r.vars.controlsContainer!==""&&(r.controlsContainer=e(r.vars.controlsContainer).length>0&&e(r.vars.controlsContainer));r.vars.manualControls!==""&&(r.manualControls=e(r.vars.manualControls).length>0&&e(r.vars.manualControls));if(r.vars.randomize){r.slides.sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-.5});r.container.empty().append(r.slides)}r.doMath();r.setup("init");r.vars.controlNav&&v.controlNav.setup();r.vars.directionNav&&v.directionNav.setup();r.vars.keyboard&&(e(r.containerSelector).length===1||r.vars.multipleKeyboard)&&e(document).bind("keyup",function(e){var t=e.keyCode;if(!r.animating&&(t===39||t===37)){var n=t===39?r.getTarget("next"):t===37?r.getTarget("prev"):!1;r.flexAnimate(n,r.vars.pauseOnAction)}});r.vars.mousewheel&&r.bind("mousewheel",function(e,t,n,i){e.preventDefault();var s=t<0?r.getTarget("next"):r.getTarget("prev");r.flexAnimate(s,r.vars.pauseOnAction)});r.vars.pausePlay&&v.pausePlay.setup();r.vars.slideshow&&r.vars.pauseInvisible&&v.pauseInvisible.init();if(r.vars.slideshow){r.vars.pauseOnHover&&r.hover(function(){!r.manualPlay&&!r.manualPause&&r.pause()},function(){!r.manualPause&&!r.manualPlay&&!r.stopped&&r.play()});if(!r.vars.pauseInvisible||!v.pauseInvisible.isHidden())r.vars.initDelay>0?r.startTimeout=setTimeout(r.play,r.vars.initDelay):r.play()}d&&v.asNav.setup();o&&r.vars.touch&&v.touch();(!p||p&&r.vars.smoothHeight)&&e(window).bind("resize orientationchange focus",v.resize);r.find("img").attr("draggable","false");setTimeout(function(){r.vars.start(r)},200)},asNav:{setup:function(){r.asNav=!0;r.animatingTo=Math.floor(r.currentSlide/r.move);r.currentItem=r.currentSlide;r.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(r.currentItem).addClass(i+"active-slide");if(!s)r.slides.click(function(t){t.preventDefault();var n=e(this),s=n.index(),o=n.offset().left-e(r).scrollLeft();if(o<=0&&n.hasClass(i+"active-slide"))r.flexAnimate(r.getTarget("prev"),!0);else if(!e(r.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider").animating&&!n.hasClass(i+"active-slide")){r.direction=r.currentItem<s?"next":"prev";r.flexAnimate(s,r.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0,!0)}});else{t._slider=r;r.slides.each(function(){var t=this;t._gesture=new MSGesture;t._gesture.target=t;t.addEventListener("MSPointerDown",function(e){e.preventDefault();e.currentTarget._gesture&&e.currentTarget._gesture.addPointer(e.pointerId)},!1);t.addEventListener("MSGestureTap",function(t){t.preventDefault();var n=e(this),i=n.index();if(!e(r.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider").animating&&!n.hasClass("active")){r.direction=r.currentItem<i?"next":"prev";r.flexAnimate(i,r.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0,!0)}})})}}},controlNav:{setup:function(){r.manualControls?v.controlNav.setupManual():v.controlNav.setupPaging()},setupPaging:function(){var t=r.vars.controlNav==="thumbnails"?"control-thumbs":"control-paging",n=1,s,o;r.controlNavScaffold=e('<ol class="'+i+"control-nav "+i+t+'"></ol>');if(r.pagingCount>1)for(var f=0;f<r.pagingCount;f++){o=r.slides.eq(f);s=r.vars.controlNav==="thumbnails"?'<img src="'+o.attr("data-thumb")+'"/>':"<a>"+n+"</a>";if("thumbnails"===r.vars.controlNav&&!0===r.vars.thumbCaptions){var l=o.attr("data-thumbcaption");""!=l&&undefined!=l&&(s+='<span class="'+i+'caption">'+l+"</span>")}r.controlNavScaffold.append("<li>"+s+"</li>");n++}r.controlsContainer?e(r.controlsContainer).append(r.controlNavScaffold):r.append(r.controlNavScaffold);v.controlNav.set();v.controlNav.active();r.controlNavScaffold.delegate("a, img",u,function(t){t.preventDefault();if(a===""||a===t.type){var n=e(this),s=r.controlNav.index(n);if(!n.hasClass(i+"active")){r.direction=s>r.currentSlide?"next":"prev";r.flexAnimate(s,r.vars.pauseOnAction)}}a===""&&(a=t.type);v.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},setupManual:function(){r.controlNav=r.manualControls;v.controlNav.active();r.controlNav.bind(u,function(t){t.preventDefault();if(a===""||a===t.type){var n=e(this),s=r.controlNav.index(n);if(!n.hasClass(i+"active")){s>r.currentSlide?r.direction="next":r.direction="prev";r.flexAnimate(s,r.vars.pauseOnAction)}}a===""&&(a=t.type);v.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},set:function(){var t=r.vars.controlNav==="thumbnails"?"img":"a";r.controlNav=e("."+i+"control-nav li "+t,r.controlsContainer?r.controlsContainer:r)},active:function(){r.controlNav.removeClass(i+"active").eq(r.animatingTo).addClass(i+"active")},update:function(t,n){r.pagingCount>1&&t==="add"?r.controlNavScaffold.append(e("<li><a>"+r.count+"</a></li>")):r.pagingCount===1?r.controlNavScaffold.find("li").remove():r.controlNav.eq(n).closest("li").remove();v.controlNav.set();r.pagingCount>1&&r.pagingCount!==r.controlNav.length?r.update(n,t):v.controlNav.active()}},directionNav:{setup:function(){var t=e('<ul class="'+i+'direction-nav"><li><a class="'+i+'prev" href="#">'+r.vars.prevText+'</a></li><li><a class="'+i+'next" href="#">'+r.vars.nextText+"</a></li></ul>");if(r.controlsContainer){e(r.controlsContainer).append(t);r.directionNav=e("."+i+"direction-nav li a",r.controlsContainer)}else{r.append(t);r.directionNav=e("."+i+"direction-nav li a",r)}v.directionNav.update();r.directionNav.bind(u,function(t){t.preventDefault();var n;if(a===""||a===t.type){n=e(this).hasClass(i+"next")?r.getTarget("next"):r.getTarget("prev");r.flexAnimate(n,r.vars.pauseOnAction)}a===""&&(a=t.type);v.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},update:function(){var e=i+"disabled";r.pagingCount===1?r.directionNav.addClass(e).attr("tabindex","-1"):r.vars.animationLoop?r.directionNav.removeClass(e).removeAttr("tabindex"):r.animatingTo===0?r.directionNav.removeClass(e).filter("."+i+"prev").addClass(e).attr("tabindex","-1"):r.animatingTo===r.last?r.directionNav.removeClass(e).filter("."+i+"next").addClass(e).attr("tabindex","-1"):r.directionNav.removeClass(e).removeAttr("tabindex")}},pausePlay:{setup:function(){var t=e('<div class="'+i+'pauseplay"><a></a></div>');if(r.controlsContainer){r.controlsContainer.append(t);r.pausePlay=e("."+i+"pauseplay a",r.controlsContainer)}else{r.append(t);r.pausePlay=e("."+i+"pauseplay a",r)}v.pausePlay.update(r.vars.slideshow?i+"pause":i+"play");r.pausePlay.bind(u,function(t){t.preventDefault();if(a===""||a===t.type)if(e(this).hasClass(i+"pause")){r.manualPause=!0;r.manualPlay=!1;r.pause()}else{r.manualPause=!1;r.manualPlay=!0;r.play()}a===""&&(a=t.type);v.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},update:function(e){e==="play"?r.pausePlay.removeClass(i+"pause").addClass(i+"play").html(r.vars.playText):r.pausePlay.removeClass(i+"play").addClass(i+"pause").html(r.vars.pauseText)}},touch:function(){var e,n,i,o,u,a,f=!1,d=0,v=0,m=0;if(!s){t.addEventListener("touchstart",g,!1);function g(s){if(r.animating)s.preventDefault();else if(window.navigator.msPointerEnabled||s.touches.length===1){r.pause();o=l?r.h:r.w;a=Number(new Date);d=s.touches[0].pageX;v=s.touches[0].pageY;i=h&&c&&r.animatingTo===r.last?0:h&&c?r.limit-(r.itemW+r.vars.itemMargin)*r.move*r.animatingTo:h&&r.currentSlide===r.last?r.limit:h?(r.itemW+r.vars.itemMargin)*r.move*r.currentSlide:c?(r.last-r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset)*o:(r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset)*o;e=l?v:d;n=l?d:v;t.addEventListener("touchmove",y,!1);t.addEventListener("touchend",b,!1)}}function y(t){d=t.touches[0].pageX;v=t.touches[0].pageY;u=l?e-v:e-d;f=l?Math.abs(u)<Math.abs(d-n):Math.abs(u)<Math.abs(v-n);var s=500;if(!f||Number(new Date)-a>s){t.preventDefault();if(!p&&r.transitions){r.vars.animationLoop||(u/=r.currentSlide===0&&u<0||r.currentSlide===r.last&&u>0?Math.abs(u)/o+2:1);r.setProps(i+u,"setTouch")}}}function b(s){t.removeEventListener("touchmove",y,!1);if(r.animatingTo===r.currentSlide&&!f&&u!==null){var l=c?-u:u,h=l>0?r.getTarget("next"):r.getTarget("prev");r.canAdvance(h)&&(Number(new Date)-a<550&&Math.abs(l)>50||Math.abs(l)>o/2)?r.flexAnimate(h,r.vars.pauseOnAction):p||r.flexAnimate(r.currentSlide,r.vars.pauseOnAction,!0)}t.removeEventListener("touchend",b,!1);e=null;n=null;u=null;i=null}}else{t.style.msTouchAction="none";t._gesture=new MSGesture;t._gesture.target=t;t.addEventListener("MSPointerDown",w,!1);t._slider=r;t.addEventListener("MSGestureChange",E,!1);t.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd",S,!1);function w(e){e.stopPropagation();if(r.animating)e.preventDefault();else{r.pause();t._gesture.addPointer(e.pointerId);m=0;o=l?r.h:r.w;a=Number(new Date);i=h&&c&&r.animatingTo===r.last?0:h&&c?r.limit-(r.itemW+r.vars.itemMargin)*r.move*r.animatingTo:h&&r.currentSlide===r.last?r.limit:h?(r.itemW+r.vars.itemMargin)*r.move*r.currentSlide:c?(r.last-r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset)*o:(r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset)*o}}function E(e){e.stopPropagation();var n=e.target._slider;if(!n)return;var r=-e.translationX,s=-e.translationY;m+=l?s:r;u=m;f=l?Math.abs(m)<Math.abs(-r):Math.abs(m)<Math.abs(-s);if(e.detail===e.MSGESTURE_FLAG_INERTIA){setImmediate(function(){t._gesture.stop()});return}if(!f||Number(new Date)-a>500){e.preventDefault();if(!p&&n.transitions){n.vars.animationLoop||(u=m/(n.currentSlide===0&&m<0||n.currentSlide===n.last&&m>0?Math.abs(m)/o+2:1));n.setProps(i+u,"setTouch")}}}function S(t){t.stopPropagation();var r=t.target._slider;if(!r)return;if(r.animatingTo===r.currentSlide&&!f&&u!==null){var s=c?-u:u,l=s>0?r.getTarget("next"):r.getTarget("prev");r.canAdvance(l)&&(Number(new Date)-a<550&&Math.abs(s)>50||Math.abs(s)>o/2)?r.flexAnimate(l,r.vars.pauseOnAction):p||r.flexAnimate(r.currentSlide,r.vars.pauseOnAction,!0)}e=null;n=null;u=null;i=null;m=0}}},resize:function(){if(!r.animating&&r.is(":visible")){h||r.doMath();if(p)v.smoothHeight();else if(h){r.slides.width(r.computedW);r.update(r.pagingCount);r.setProps()}else if(l){r.viewport.height(r.h);r.setProps(r.h,"setTotal")}else{r.vars.smoothHeight&&v.smoothHeight();r.newSlides.width(r.computedW);r.setProps(r.computedW,"setTotal")}}},smoothHeight:function(e){if(!l||p){var t=p?r:r.viewport;e?t.animate({height:r.slides.eq(r.animatingTo).height()},e):t.height(r.slides.eq(r.animatingTo).height())}},sync:function(t){var n=e(r.vars.sync).data("flexslider"),i=r.animatingTo;switch(t){case"animate":n.flexAnimate(i,r.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0);break;case"play":!n.playing&&!n.asNav&&n.play();break;case"pause":n.pause()}},pauseInvisible:{visProp:null,init:function(){var e=["webkit","moz","ms","o"];if("hidden"in document)return"hidden";for(var t=0;t<e.length;t++)e[t]+"Hidden"in document&&(v.pauseInvisible.visProp=e[t]+"Hidden");if(v.pauseInvisible.visProp){var n=v.pauseInvisible.visProp.replace(/[H|h]idden/,"")+"visibilitychange";document.addEventListener(n,function(){v.pauseInvisible.isHidden()?r.startTimeout?clearTimeout(r.startTimeout):r.pause():r.started?r.play():r.vars.initDelay>0?setTimeout(r.play,r.vars.initDelay):r.play()})}},isHidden:function(){return document[v.pauseInvisible.visProp]||!1}},setToClearWatchedEvent:function(){clearTimeout(f);f=setTimeout(function(){a=""},3e3)}};r.flexAnimate=function(t,n,s,u,a){!r.vars.animationLoop&&t!==r.currentSlide&&(r.direction=t>r.currentSlide?"next":"prev");d&&r.pagingCount===1&&(r.direction=r.currentItem<t?"next":"prev");if(!r.animating&&(r.canAdvance(t,a)||s)&&r.is(":visible")){if(d&&u){var f=e(r.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider");r.atEnd=t===0||t===r.count-1;f.flexAnimate(t,!0,!1,!0,a);r.direction=r.currentItem<t?"next":"prev";f.direction=r.direction;if(Math.ceil((t+1)/r.visible)-1===r.currentSlide||t===0){r.currentItem=t;r.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(t).addClass(i+"active-slide");return!1}r.currentItem=t;r.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(t).addClass(i+"active-slide");t=Math.floor(t/r.visible)}r.animating=!0;r.animatingTo=t;n&&r.pause();r.vars.before(r);r.syncExists&&!a&&v.sync("animate");r.vars.controlNav&&v.controlNav.active();h||r.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(t).addClass(i+"active-slide");r.atEnd=t===0||t===r.last;r.vars.directionNav&&v.directionNav.update();if(t===r.last){r.vars.end(r);r.vars.animationLoop||r.pause()}if(!p){var m=l?r.slides.filter(":first").height():r.computedW,g,y,b;if(h){g=r.vars.itemMargin;b=(r.itemW+g)*r.move*r.animatingTo;y=b>r.limit&&r.visible!==1?r.limit:b}else r.currentSlide===0&&t===r.count-1&&r.vars.animationLoop&&r.direction!=="next"?y=c?(r.count+r.cloneOffset)*m:0:r.currentSlide===r.last&&t===0&&r.vars.animationLoop&&r.direction!=="prev"?y=c?0:(r.count+1)*m:y=c?(r.count-1-t+r.cloneOffset)*m:(t+r.cloneOffset)*m;r.setProps(y,"",r.vars.animationSpeed);if(r.transitions){if(!r.vars.animationLoop||!r.atEnd){r.animating=!1;r.currentSlide=r.animatingTo}r.container.unbind("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend");r.container.bind("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend",function(){r.wrapup(m)})}else r.container.animate(r.args,r.vars.animationSpeed,r.vars.easing,function(){r.wrapup(m)})}else if(!o){r.slides.eq(r.currentSlide).css({zIndex:1}).animate({opacity:0},r.vars.animationSpeed,r.vars.easing);r.slides.eq(t).css({zIndex:2}).animate({opacity:1},r.vars.animationSpeed,r.vars.easing,r.wrapup)}else{r.slides.eq(r.currentSlide).css({opacity:0,zIndex:1});r.slides.eq(t).css({opacity:1,zIndex:2});r.wrapup(m)}r.vars.smoothHeight&&v.smoothHeight(r.vars.animationSpeed)}};r.wrapup=function(e){!p&&!h&&(r.currentSlide===0&&r.animatingTo===r.last&&r.vars.animationLoop?r.setProps(e,"jumpEnd"):r.currentSlide===r.last&&r.animatingTo===0&&r.vars.animationLoop&&r.setProps(e,"jumpStart"));r.animating=!1;r.currentSlide=r.animatingTo;r.vars.after(r)};r.animateSlides=function(){!r.animating&&m&&r.flexAnimate(r.getTarget("next"))};r.pause=function(){clearInterval(r.animatedSlides);r.animatedSlides=null;r.playing=!1;r.vars.pausePlay&&v.pausePlay.update("play");r.syncExists&&v.sync("pause")};r.play=function(){r.playing&&clearInterval(r.animatedSlides);r.animatedSlides=r.animatedSlides||setInterval(r.animateSlides,r.vars.slideshowSpeed);r.started=r.playing=!0;r.vars.pausePlay&&v.pausePlay.update("pause");r.syncExists&&v.sync("play")};r.stop=function(){r.pause();r.stopped=!0};r.canAdvance=function(e,t){var n=d?r.pagingCount-1:r.last;return t?!0:d&&r.currentItem===r.count-1&&e===0&&r.direction==="prev"?!0:d&&r.currentItem===0&&e===r.pagingCount-1&&r.direction!=="next"?!1:e===r.currentSlide&&!d?!1:r.vars.animationLoop?!0:r.atEnd&&r.currentSlide===0&&e===n&&r.direction!=="next"?!1:r.atEnd&&r.currentSlide===n&&e===0&&r.direction==="next"?!1:!0};r.getTarget=function(e){r.direction=e;return e==="next"?r.currentSlide===r.last?0:r.currentSlide+1:r.currentSlide===0?r.last:r.currentSlide-1};r.setProps=function(e,t,n){var i=function(){var n=e?e:(r.itemW+r.vars.itemMargin)*r.move*r.animatingTo,i=function(){if(h)return t==="setTouch"?e:c&&r.animatingTo===r.last?0:c?r.limit-(r.itemW+r.vars.itemMargin)*r.move*r.animatingTo:r.animatingTo===r.last?r.limit:n;switch(t){case"setTotal":return c?(r.count-1-r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset)*e:(r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset)*e;case"setTouch":return c?e:e;case"jumpEnd":return c?e:r.count*e;case"jumpStart":return c?r.count*e:e;default:return e}}();return i*-1+"px"}();if(r.transitions){i=l?"translate3d(0,"+i+",0)":"translate3d("+i+",0,0)";n=n!==undefined?n/1e3+"s":"0s";r.container.css("-"+r.pfx+"-transition-duration",n)}r.args[r.prop]=i;(r.transitions||n===undefined)&&r.container.css(r.args)};r.setup=function(t){if(!p){var n,s;if(t==="init"){r.viewport=e('<div class="'+i+'viewport"></div>').css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"}).appendTo(r).append(r.container);r.cloneCount=0;r.cloneOffset=0;if(c){s=e.makeArray(r.slides).reverse();r.slides=e(s);r.container.empty().append(r.slides)}}if(r.vars.animationLoop&&!h){r.cloneCount=2;r.cloneOffset=1;t!=="init"&&r.container.find(".clone").remove();r.container.append(r.slides.first().clone().addClass("clone").attr("aria-hidden","true")).prepend(r.slides.last().clone().addClass("clone").attr("aria-hidden","true"))}r.newSlides=e(r.vars.selector,r);n=c?r.count-1-r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset:r.currentSlide+r.cloneOffset;if(l&&!h){r.container.height((r.count+r.cloneCount)*200+"%").css("position","absolute").width("100%");setTimeout(function(){r.newSlides.css({display:"block"});r.doMath();r.viewport.height(r.h);r.setProps(n*r.h,"init")},t==="init"?100:0)}else{r.container.width((r.count+r.cloneCount)*200+"%");r.setProps(n*r.computedW,"init");setTimeout(function(){r.doMath();r.newSlides.css({width:r.computedW,"float":"left",display:"block"});r.vars.smoothHeight&&v.smoothHeight()},t==="init"?100:0)}}else{r.slides.css({width:"100%","float":"left",marginRight:"-100%",position:"relative"});t==="init"&&(o?r.slides.css({opacity:0,display:"block",webkitTransition:"opacity "+r.vars.animationSpeed/1e3+"s ease",zIndex:1}).eq(r.currentSlide).css({opacity:1,zIndex:2}):r.slides.css({opacity:0,display:"block",zIndex:1}).eq(r.currentSlide).css({zIndex:2}).animate({opacity:1},r.vars.animationSpeed,r.vars.easing));r.vars.smoothHeight&&v.smoothHeight()}h||r.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(r.currentSlide).addClass(i+"active-slide")};r.doMath=function(){var e=r.slides.first(),t=r.vars.itemMargin,n=r.vars.minItems,i=r.vars.maxItems;r.w=r.viewport===undefined?r.width():r.viewport.width();r.h=e.height();r.boxPadding=e.outerWidth()-e.width();if(h){r.itemT=r.vars.itemWidth+t;r.minW=n?n*r.itemT:r.w;r.maxW=i?i*r.itemT-t:r.w;r.itemW=r.minW>r.w?(r.w-t*(n-1))/n:r.maxW<r.w?(r.w-t*(i-1))/i:r.vars.itemWidth>r.w?r.w:r.vars.itemWidth;r.visible=Math.floor(r.w/r.itemW);r.move=r.vars.move>0&&r.vars.move<r.visible?r.vars.move:r.visible;r.pagingCount=Math.ceil((r.count-r.visible)/r.move+1);r.last=r.pagingCount-1;r.limit=r.pagingCount===1?0:r.vars.itemWidth>r.w?r.itemW*(r.count-1)+t*(r.count-1):(r.itemW+t)*r.count-r.w-t}else{r.itemW=r.w;r.pagingCount=r.count;r.last=r.count-1}r.computedW=r.itemW-r.boxPadding};r.update=function(e,t){r.doMath();if(!h){e<r.currentSlide?r.currentSlide+=1:e<=r.currentSlide&&e!==0&&(r.currentSlide-=1);r.animatingTo=r.currentSlide}if(r.vars.controlNav&&!r.manualControls)if(t==="add"&&!h||r.pagingCount>r.controlNav.length)v.controlNav.update("add");else if(t==="remove"&&!h||r.pagingCount<r.controlNav.length){if(h&&r.currentSlide>r.last){r.currentSlide-=1;r.animatingTo-=1}v.controlNav.update("remove",r.last)}r.vars.directionNav&&v.directionNav.update()};r.addSlide=function(t,n){var i=e(t);r.count+=1;r.last=r.count-1;l&&c?n!==undefined?r.slides.eq(r.count-n).after(i):r.container.prepend(i):n!==undefined?r.slides.eq(n).before(i):r.container.append(i);r.update(n,"add");r.slides=e(r.vars.selector+":not(.clone)",r);r.setup();r.vars.added(r)};r.removeSlide=function(t){var n=isNaN(t)?r.slides.index(e(t)):t;r.count-=1;r.last=r.count-1;isNaN(t)?e(t,r.slides).remove():l&&c?r.slides.eq(r.last).remove():r.slides.eq(t).remove();r.doMath();r.update(n,"remove");r.slides=e(r.vars.selector+":not(.clone)",r);r.setup();r.vars.removed(r)};v.init()};e(window).blur(function(e){focused=!1}).focus(function(e){focused=!0});e.flexslider.defaults={namespace:"flex-",selector:".slides > li",animation:"fade",easing:"swing",direction:"horizontal",reverse:!1,animationLoop:!0,smoothHeight:!1,startAt:0,slideshow:!0,slideshowSpeed:7e3,animationSpeed:600,initDelay:0,randomize:!1,thumbCaptions:!1,pauseOnAction:!0,pauseOnHover:!1,pauseInvisible:!0,useCSS:!0,touch:!0,video:!1,controlNav:!0,directionNav:!0,prevText:"Previous",nextText:"Next",keyboard:!0,multipleKeyboard:!1,mousewheel:!1,pausePlay:!1,pauseText:"Pause",playText:"Play",controlsContainer:"",manualControls:"",sync:"",asNavFor:"",itemWidth:0,itemMargin:0,minItems:1,maxItems:0,move:0,allowOneSlide:!0,start:function(){},before:function(){},after:function(){},end:function(){},added:function(){},removed:function(){}};e.fn.flexslider=function(t){t===undefined&&(t={});if(typeof t=="object")return this.each(function(){var n=e(this),r=t.selector?t.selector:".slides > li",i=n.find(r);if(i.length===1&&t.allowOneSlide===!0||i.length===0){i.fadeIn(400);t.start&&t.start(n)}else n.data("flexslider")===undefined&&new e.flexslider(this,t)});var n=e(this).data("flexslider");switch(t){case"play":n.play();break;case"pause":n.pause();break;case"stop":n.stop();break;case"next":n.flexAnimate(n.getTarget("next"),!0);break;case"prev":case"previous":n.flexAnimate(n.getTarget("prev"),!0);break;default:typeof t=="number"&&n.flexAnimate(t,!0)}}})(jQuery);
```

I know it looks crazy, I was looking for a tool to organize it but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the bit of code that initiates the flexslider - it will look something like this:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider();
```

I thought it should slide as default but if it doesn't then you need to make sure the initiation has the following setting set:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationSpeed: 500, // the speed of the animation in milliseconds
    slideshowSpeed: 4000 // the speed of the slideshow in milliseconds
});
```

[More information about what options you can use when initiating Flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties)

[Basic example of flexslider with auto scrolling](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html)

**EDIT**
Having just looked at the theme you linked to, are you sure it is using flexslider, it seems to include the library but never uses it.  The top banner slider is a [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) - to start this you will need to use the [`autoStart` option](http://bxslider.com/options), and the middle carousel is an [owl-carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    captions: true,
    mode: 'fade', 
    autoStart: true,
    pause: 4000 // The amount of time (in ms) between each auto transition
});+
```

Answer (score -1):

First it's not very useful to post the whole minified library.

Second: You can use the `setInterval(<function>, <interval in ms>)` function to trigger the slide.